# Google maps api and geolocation, Javascript and Html

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

Hey I'm new to the google maps api, and I have an embedded map, i'm using geolocation to get the users lat and long, and i'm then filling in the gaps in the maps api. The map, however doesn't work when I use the generated lat and long, but does work if i just type one in

**Non-working code:**

```
     var map;
  var infowindow;

  function initialize() {

    if (navigator.geolocation)
   {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    function showPosition(position)
    {

    var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng( position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude );

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: latlon,
      zoom: 15,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    });

    var request = {
      location: latlon,
      radius: 555,
      types: ['bar']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
     }
    }
   }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      alert(place.name);
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**Working code**

```
 var map;
  var infowindow;

  function initialize() {
    var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: latlon,
      zoom: 15,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    });

    var request = {
      location: latlon,
      radius: 555,
      types: ['bar']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      alert(place.name);
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Any help if appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your line:

```
var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng
      (position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude);
```

with

```
var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng
      (position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
```

The problem is in concatenating two values into one where constructor expects two parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much this works perfect :) would mark you up but not enough rep and stack overflow says i can't select you as the right answer in 9 mins but this was perfect :)